# CompositeSymbol that includes TextSymbols and SimpleFillSymbol does not draw map

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

Following is the code snippet that does not draw both TextSymbols.

```
private function MapClick(evt:MapMouseEvent):void
        {
            var cs:CompositeSymbol = new CompositeSymbol();
            var textSymbol1:TextSymbol = new TextSymbol("hello");
            textSymbol1.textFormat= new TextFormat("Arial",5);
            var textSymbol2:TextSymbol = new TextSymbol("hello 123");
            textSymbol1.textFormat= new TextFormat("Arial",10);

            var myPolygon:Polygon = new Polygon(
                [[
                    evt.mapPoint,
                    new MapPoint(evt.mapPoint.x+5, evt.mapPoint.y+8),
                    new MapPoint(evt.mapPoint.x+10, evt.mapPoint.y+12)
                ]], new SpatialReference(4326));
            cs.symbols= [textSymbol1, textSymbol2, new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_BACKWARD_DIAGONAL,0xFF00FF,1)];
            var m_graphic:Graphic = new Graphic(myPolygon , cs );
            gLayer.add( m_graphic );
        }
```

TextSymbols accept point geometry and I am assigning them with multipoint geometry I think that is where problem lies. I need to draw TextSymbols all around the polygon so how can I accomplish it. I am using FlexViewer 2.5.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks